# Custom circular views

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls, custom-component

I want to make menus like mentioned in image that will worked on android.

[image: Circular menu list]

If you seen image at left half circle is diplayed. I want to rotate this circle after rotation it will display other hidden menus. Also at right sub menus of center main will be displayed.

Comment: how do you want the user to use this circular menu? Will this rotate as the user scrolls/flings or just rotates on click on items??

Comment: ya i want to scroll on flings/ if user clicks on last item next item will displayed or if user clicks on first item its previous item will displayed also changed position of clicked item to center.

Comment: This http://code.beaucollins.com/radial-menu/ might help you

Comment: Its just design that we made. Until now i never created this menus.

Comment: the best way is to create a custom Vertical 3D carousel, relay on this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Comment: have you develope this?